# Failed to create Shared Library using android-ndk in Linux?

Tags: android, linux, build, android-ndk

While trying to create a shared library using android-ndk-r8b it shows the error

```
Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file /home/myLib/ndk1/jni/Android.mk 
Android NDK Aborting...    .Stop
```

For my application,I simply created a jni folder which contains a ndk1.c file and Android.mk file

Steps for building library:

```
export ARM_ROOT=/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b
    export ARM_TOOL=/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-   
4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86
    export ARM_LIB=/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib
    export ARM_LIBO=/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3
    export ARM_INC=/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include
    export ARM_PRE=arm-linux-androideabi
    export NDK=/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b 
    export PATH=$PATH:/home/myLib/android-ndk-r8b
    export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/home/myLib/ndk1
```

Please help with your valuable suggestions!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good  tutorial for ndk beginners 
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

In tutorial :
as you are building on android-ndk-r8b
replace step which says

```
go to  your NDK-HOME and  run  make APP=ndk_demo
```

do this

```
go to your android project directory and run ndk-build in terminal
```

Checklist

1) Make sure path NDK path is set

2) Make sure you generated the header file and moved to jni folder

3) You copied appropriate function signature from the header file to your c file
this a place people make mistakes while referring to examples they blindly copy the function signature while using some other package name and class name.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_your_package_class_method(JNIEnv *d, jobject e, jstring f);
```

4)Make file is present inside your jni folder and contains the correct c file name

5)You are running ndk-build in correct directory ,i.e., project home directory

Answer (score 1):

try verbose with the "ndk-build".... So you can follow step-by-step what the build is doing with the instructions in the .mk

ndk-build -B V=1

use above for more details ....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you please explain the ndk-build step that you mentioned? Since i'm a beginner in building shared library.

Comment: where did u install the NDK? read all the html files in $ $NDK/docs directory. if you are not familiar with the discreet steps , you can read about them in the GNU documentation ( CC, LD, NM, AR )