# android NDK build issue

Tags: android, android-ndk

when I tried the NDK build command  here is the error i got

```
        D:\AndroidWorkSpace\cppTestProj>D:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-b
uild.cmd
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for m
odule cppTestProj
Android NDK:   LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=
"Compile++ thumb : cppTestProj <= maintestapp.cpp
jni/maintestapp.cpp:1:19: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cppTestProj/maintestapp.o] Error 1
```

The JNI folder has the following files:

```
maintestapp.cpp
Test_array_type.cpp
Test_array_type.h
```

Could u pls let me know the issue. Im not using Cygwin for the same. Am I missing any files?

Here is the make file

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := cppTestProj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := LOCAL_SRC_FILES := maintestapp.cpp \
                   Test_array_type.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

here is the cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Test_array_type.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Test_array_type test_array;
    Test_array_type *ptest_array1;

    test_array.AddToList(10);
    test_array.AddToList(20);
    test_array.AddToList("Basha");
    test_array.PrintList();
    ptest_array1 = test_array.clonelist();
    test_array.DeleteFromList(3);
    test_array.AddToList(10);
    test_array.AddToList(20);
    test_array.AddToList(30);
    test_array.AddToList(40);
    test_array.AddToList(true);
    test_array.AddToList("Java Beon APP");
    test_array.PrintList();
    ptest_array1->PrintList();
    getch();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you should execute your `ndk-build` command from root firectory of your project not from `jni` directory.please run that command from root directory of your project.

Comment: Show your Android.mk file code

Comment: @Dharmendra Im new to this and did not yet prepare the make file. Could you let know as how could it be done.

Comment: @juned 
 D:\AndroidWorkSpace\cppTestProj\jni------> this is my proj directory itself and I have given the build command from there itself

Comment: Run that Build command from here `D:\AndroidWorkSpace\cppTestProj\`

Comment: @junedD:\AndroidWorkSpace\cppTestProj>D:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-b
uild.cmd
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for m
odule <cppTestProj>
Android NDK:   Test_array_type.cpp>
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/<cppTestProj>/<maintestapp.o] Error 1
 and here is the make file code LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) include $(CLEAR_VARS) LOCAL_MODULE := <cppTestProj> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <maintestapp.cpp Test_array_type.cpp > include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Sai add this log  in your question as update and you can  check my answer here might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511580/failed-to-create-shared-library-using-android-ndk-in-linux/12639723#12639723

Comment: don't define `Test_array_type.h` file in `Android.mk`.just include that header file in your .cpp file then run again

Comment: @juned pls find the updated query in the question asked

Comment: Are you sure the <> signs are needed in LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <maintestapp.cpp Test_array_type.cpp> ? Looks like the builder thinks "cpp>" is the extension.

Comment: @juned i changed tha make file as per ur advices ..pls find the updated question

Comment: @Márton Molnár it worked removing the angular braces but still Im stuck with other issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should not run the 'ndk-build' command from your projects `jni` folder. To execute the `Android.mk` file run `ndk-bild` command within your root directory of project.

Your `Android.mk` should be look like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := cppTestProj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := maintestapp.cpp \
                   Test_array_type.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then run your `ndk-build` command

You can see this link for sample [Android.mk](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/jni/Android.mk) file

**Update:**

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
```

for more information please refer `HelloJni.java` file of sample project.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please specify the issue? and why this `LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=` line is two times.

Comment: I changed it to one line. I tried making a hello world program in C and have given the name of the file in android.mk too and tried executing the build command

Comment: you can try to run the Android sample application `hello-jni` which is bundled with android NDK. try to run that application first.

Comment: I got this as the output in command prompt
D:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\samples\hello-jni>D:\android-ndk-r8b-
windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build.cmd
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
"Compile thumb : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so

Comment: this means you have build successfully now you can load that `libhello-jni.so`. see the update

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18566/discussion-between-saidinakargm-and-juned)

Comment: why not including the .h files in LOCAL_SRC_FILES. @juned

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` and include your visual C++ include folders, since you are obviuosly working with it.